# 6 yo cat not eating or drinking, ideas?

Tags: cats, health, diseases

He is generally healthy but just tapered off yesterday and has resisted all food and fluids today. We have given some liquids by syringe but at this efforts he screams. He is definitely dehydrated. He seems interested in food but then won't eat it.

His respirations and temperature are normal. He won't let us take pulse or look in mouth. He had good urine output last night.  10 days ago he had teeth cleaned and a full blood workup.  Platelets are low.  All else is normal except glucose and creatinin which are high and doctor attributes it to stress.

We will take him to vet in AM but any ideas before then?

Thanks!

Comment: Could be darned near anything, I'm afraid. Physical exam definitely appropriate

Comment: He has been at the vets since Monday 9am.  Exray shows gas on stomach.  Is on IV fluid and has peed.  Running new blood tests and still no idea whats wrong.  : (

Comment: Wishing  you and him good luck, and a comfortable passing if it comes to that

Comment: No conclusion what was wrong but he just came home and is doing great!  Certainly not ready to go from sick to dead!

Comment: @monroe Glad to hear he is doing better! Always good when these stories have a happy ending.

Answer (score 0):

Take him to the vets and do what they say. There is not much you can do. He is an older cat. Maybe he is ill or something, or has a bad stomach ache. I would let the vet tell you what to do for your pet as he seems to be in safe hands.